# Imposing leads and lags into a sequence without a for loop

Tags: f#

Aside from writing a loop that yields values, is there a simple/clean functional way of creating a lag (previous value) within a sequence.

Eg.  If my sequence is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` and my lag is `1` return a tuple that is

```
(Some(1), None), (Some(2), Some(1)), (Some(3), Some(2))...(Some(10), Some(9))
```

A lag of `2` would give `(Some(1), None), (Some(2), None), (Some(3), Some(1))...`

It's obviously easy to write this using a loop, but is that the right way?

Comment: You probably want a function that takes a sequence and returns a sequence. Tuples in F# always have a fixed length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the functions in the Seq module:

```
let lag n sequence =
    sequence
    |> Seq.map Some
    |> Seq.append (Seq.init n (fun _ -> None))
    |> Seq.zip sequence

lag 2 [1..5] |> Seq.toList
> [(1, null); (2, null); (3, Some 1); (4, Some 2); (5, Some 3)]
```

Comment: @Daniel. All fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

petebu's answer (once a few mistakes are corrected) is a better answer. But I'll leave this here anyway.

```
let withLag n (source: seq<_>) =
  source
    |> Seq.windowed n
    |> Seq.append (Seq.init n (fun _ -> [||]))
    |> Seq.zip source
    |> Seq.map (fun (x, arr) ->
      let laggedValue = if arr.Length > 0 then Some arr.[0] else None
      (x, laggedValue))

let l = List.init 5 id
l |> withLag 2 |> Seq.toList |> printfn "%A"

> [(0, null); (1, null); (2, Some 0); (3, Some 1); (4, Some 2)]
```